# QT QAudiooutput only playing through left ear while in stereo

Tags: qt

What i have currently is an attempt to have a signal generator play in stereo. What is currently happening is while the format has been accepted it winds up only playing the audio from the left ear. However when i switch to mono it works fine through both ears however what i want to do is have it where i can control which ear i am listening from. For instance if i only want it to play on the left ear all i will hear is the audio on the left ear, however i also want to ability to switch ears or use both. The current method i am using is as follows.

```
    format.setFrequency(44100);
    format.setChannels(2);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    //This is just the format setup.

    // i am using push mode for this program
    audio_outputStream = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
    audio_outputDevice = audio_outputStream->start();

    //now when i write the numbers from the signal generator i use this  method

    QByteArray array;
    array.append(integerValueThatIsConvertedToConstChar,SizeOfInt);

    //And i write the data from the ByteArray to the IODevice as such
     audio_outputDevice.write(array.data(),MaxSizeOfInt);

    //Afterwhich i remove the front of the ByteArray for the next number to be appended and wrote in. 
    array.remove(0,SizeOfInt);
```

As stated before the above steps i use in my code do work with monotone with one channel but only plays on the left side when using Stereo with 2 channels. My goal is to be able to control which channel i am writing to through push mode. I currently do not see why it currently only uses one of the two channels, am I simply not writing to the second channel?

Comment: Audio output has a preferred buffer size. Are you passing a buffer of that size with each write call?

Comment: I will have to check that, I was recently messing with the size earlier today and still had no change. The size variation i was playing with was on the write, but if i am understanding you correctly i would have to place more data into the buffer before i call the write?

Comment: Each write() should pass at least `QAudioOutput::periodSize()` bytes.

Comment: That fixed the issue of it not writing to the right channel. I wasn't using the correct size in the write. Also am i correct in assuming that the first half of the buffer of the period size would be on the left channel and the other half being the right channel?

Comment: Look into the format spec (PCM is interleaved).

Comment: According to the format spec it follows a left right left right pattern, however when attempting to utilize this i wind up with gargled noise instead of the clear 1khz tone i used to test it while i was using only one channel.

Comment: To add more detail to the above. What i had done is created a buffer of period size and attempted to place the audio data in different areas in the buffer to find where in the buffer it began to interleave. Doing so i have yet to find any portion where the audio sounds clear on both sides just sounding as a garbled mess on the left speaker,also i attempted to repeat the same value over and over just to see at which point the buffer switched from left to right it remained on the left channel. Is there a character or method i need to use to interleave the buffer?

Comment: When you simply write 1kHz, does it play through both left and right? Does it sound like 2kHz?

Comment: Originally when playing it with monotone, and before correcting it to where stereo was playing through both speakers it would play through both while on mono, but only left on stereo. It sounded like 1KHz and was verified using an oscope. as it is currently it is garbled, and if it does clear up, it remains playing on the left. Also, not sure how much help this will be but the size of the int being converted to the constant char is 4 bytes

Comment: I'm talking about playing a mono track in stereo mode. If it's interleaved then it'll just double the frequency.

Comment: Ok, and yes it is sounding higher pitch on the left speaker only. when replayed as mono it was lower.

Comment: would the method i am using to add to the buffer affect how the data is interleaved? Qbytearray's append fuction.

Comment: It's PCM 16 bits, which means 2 bytes per sample. Interleaved means 2 bytes for left, 2 bytes for the right and so on.

Comment: Finally, it's working in the sense that i can now have the controls i wanted from it. Thanks, seriously this has been driving me up a wall for a while.